# Random 7 second delay from Apache on Django with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm running into issues and have narrowed it down to Apache. I'm running Django w/Tastypie on mod_wsgi (worker mpm, daemon mode) on SSL. I'm calling the API through htaccess proxy on another server to avoid ajax cross-domain access errors.

Everything is running pretty great. However, I'm received a very random delay tapping specific items through our user interface when calling the api. It seems that the web server has a very consistent inconsistency. The lag is ALWAYS 7 seconds. It happens randomly every 5-15 minutes.

Here are my Apache settings:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers         25
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    MaxMemFree         1024
</IfModule>
```

in my vhost:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.com processes=4 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup www.domain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain/wsgi.py process-group=www.domain.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

All of the requests are served through Django are are all JSON format (pure API).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

UPDATE: I'm suspecting it is in fact most likely an Apache issue rather than a DNS issue. It looks like it's creating additional processes to serve up the request before actually responding to anything.

```
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:29 -0700] "GET /api/v1/clock/?limit=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5159 "https://www.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:29 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:29 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:30 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:29 -0700] "PATCH /api/v1/check/546d48e9-f15f-4dee-8742-864d1fc5e0f7/ HTTP/1.1" 202 7334 "https://www.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:32 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:32 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:33 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:37 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:37 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:38 -0700] "POST /api/v1/check/ HTTP/1.1" 201 1492 "https://www.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
```

Note the 8 second delay between the patch and the post. What do the blank lines mean?

```
172.31.4.91 - - [03/Aug/2013:19:01:36 -0700] "-" 408 142 "-" "-"
```

UPDATE:
Here is the point in my 'info' logs that I'm received the 7 second delay...

```
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:15 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: SSL input filter read failed.
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:15 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection closed to child 81 with standard shutdown (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 136 (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 147 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection closed to child 136 with standard shutdown (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 79 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 79 (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 17 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:16 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:17 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection closed to child 79 with standard shutdown (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:17 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 67 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:17 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 67 (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 140 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection closed to child 67 with standard shutdown (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection to child 78 established (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: SSL input filter read failed.
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:21 2013] [info] [client 172.31.28.237] Connection closed to child 144 with standard shutdown (server api.chanj.com:443)
[Sun Aug 04 13:14:26 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 78 (server api.chanj.com:443)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the network router of the place that was having problems had a UDP timeout set to 200 seconds. That was it. Nothing to do with Apache, etc. I did set the threads a lot higher and it helped, but that wasn't the cause of the lag...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in:

- [Significant overhead on Django apache vs. built-in dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914360/significant-overhead-on-django-apache-vs-built-in-dev-server)

you haven't done anything to address that you have so few threads handling requests in your WSGI application (4 total), where as Apache could try and proxy up to 150 at a time. So I wouldn't rule out that your WSGI application is starved of the ability to handle many concurrent long running requests. In other words, if you occasionally get a few long running requests, that could cause backlog of other requests and so delays.

Another potential cause for delays is simply loading time for your WSGI application on process restart. Such delays at that point could be because of preloading database information or compiling templates.

Now technically your configuration wouldn't have processes being restarted due to maximum requests, inactivity etc, but processes can restart if the WSGI script file is being touched or you are running an automatic code reloader and other code is being touched.

In order to work out whether related to process restarts, you should ensure that LogLevel is set to 'info' in Apache and monitor what mod_wsgi logs in the Apache error log about process restarts and loading of WSGI script files. Also keep an eye out for daemon processes crashing as that could also be a cause. Especially since you aren't using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Beyond that it is really difficult to speculate. I would suggest you perhaps consider using a monitoring tool. Options here are production capable systems such as New Relic, or if in a development environment, you could use Django debug toolbar. They may help to narrow down where the delay is occurring and for what web requests.

Comment: Hi Graham, I JUST posted an update to this thread at the same time you posted yours. Thanks for the info. Are the blank lines able to give you any info? So I take it that I should increase the number of threads for Apache, do you have a suggestion on what this should be? I do rarely have any long running requests (more frequency on much smaller requests). I'm not restarting any processes or making any updates during this testing time.

Comment: Bah, it's a timeout. This would go back to to this line WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.com processes=4 threads=1. I updated this to WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.com processes=25 threads=5, and will do additional testing.

Comment: I added another update from the access logs with info turned on, somewhere in these lines is where the delay is happening. I currently have MaxClients set to 75 and processes=75 threads=3.

Comment: I would really recommend you try New Relic. If the issue is occurring within the context of your actual application code, it will help narrow things down. New Relic has a free tier, plus a trial period with full functionality as well. That 75 processes, and even the 25 is potentially now excessive. The capacity analysis report of New Relic will help identify what you really need to deal with the traffic you get. See http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/11/08/new-relic-supports-python/ and http://blog.newrelic.com/2012/09/11/introducing-capacity-analysis-for-python/ for a New Relic tour.

Comment: Thanks, I did add in new relic a few days ago. The capacity analysis is showing a at max around 2.5%. Note that this is not a normal website, it's a locked-down fairly private api used strictly as a restful api. We've noticed a lot of standard thinking and logic goes out the window with our setup... Anyways I'm at 50 processes, 5 threads, and things are flying now unbelievable fast. I've tested with fairly live data but will get more info over the next few days as we increase traffic with more connections. Thanks for your help, it's been great.